# Append an array with HTML file

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, append

Its coming up like this

Once I send `IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model` data from previous action, I can filter some selectedIDs using above method

Once I run this on debug mode normally those `selectedIDs` appear like this

[image]

I need to use following method to send  that array

```
[HttpGet]  
[ValidateInput(false)]  
public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)  
{  
    // to access to all the ID's of the selected items, for example  
    IEnumerable<int> selectedIDs = model.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Property_ID);  


    PrepairEditor(delegate (Editor editor)  
    {  
        editor.LoadHtml("~/brochuretemplates/myhtml.html");  
    });  

    return View();  
}
```

So I need to send those `selectedIDs` to `myhtml.html` file

if ask that in another way ,
(if I consider this `selectedIDs` can send as an array)
I want to know how we can append above `selectedIDs` array with `editor.LoadHtml("path")` .

Comment: append them as URL parameters.

Comment: how to do that ? but here its not just a single value , actually its set of valuse

Comment: convert array to json and pass it

Comment: Do a join on your array so it looks like this: 1,2 and then just pass it on the url: editor.LoadHtml("~/brochuretemplates/myhtml.html?selectedIDs=1,2");

Comment: @StephenBrickner can you give example that I can understand easily

Comment: @vijayP has added an answer below that is doing what I suggested. That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in your controller action:

```
    IEnumerable<int> selectedIDs = model.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Property_ID);  

    string ids = string.Join(",", selectedIDs );

    PrepairEditor(delegate (Editor editor)  
    {  
        editor.LoadHtml("~/brochuretemplates/myhtml.html?selectedIDs="+ids );  
    });
```

Comment: Actually I'm loading this html file to to Rich text editor content , however I will check with your answer